# DataContractSerialization - Serialization OutofMemoryException

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer

I have a class that `serializes` and `deserializes` objects for a given type. I am trying to serialize a Custom file object containing the file name, the data in the file and a few other details like created time, modified time etc associated with the file. Additionally the `custome` class includes some properties or flags I would need  at my receiver end (where I deserialize).

When I try to serialize around 30K of such file objects, it does the serialization successfully for a large majority, but throws back an outofmemoryexception for some files.

Below is my serialization class code:

```
public static string SerializeToByteArray(Type T, object request)
        {

        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(T);
        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memStream))
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(memStream, request);
                memStream.Position = 0;
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }


    public static T DeserializeFromByteArray<T>(string xml)
    {
        DataContractSerializer deserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
            memStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            memStream.Position = 0;

            var newobj = (T)deserializer.ReadObject(memStream);
            return newobj;
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you try it in 64 bit mode?

Comment: Changing to 64 bit mode helped. Thanks.

Comment: 1) What is the traceback at which the exception is thrown?  2) If you are serializing to a file, why are you first serializing to a string?